# How to handle 404 error when an action is not found in Struts 2

Tags: error-handling, configuration, struts2, http-status-code-404, action-mapping

In Struts 2 if action is not found I want to redirect to `404.jsp` page
I have added the error code in `web.xml` file as below.

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/403.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

It rendering the `404.jsp` page content but in log below error coming.
How to remove the below error

```
2014-04-07 14:07:46,706  WARN (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher:64) - Could not find action or result: /struts2-test/home11
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [home11] associated with context path [/struts2-test]. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:185)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:37)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:552)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Breakpoint at `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher:64`.

Comment: Thanks for your response
I didn't get you.
Can you please explain me in details

Comment: What is the content of error page?

Comment: I have updated the content of error page in above question.

If action not found then it should redirect to the 404 page and don't through the warning, so how can i achive this.

Comment: Post the error page, seems like what you want is not possible, the warning is produced by the framework using their loging and you have to do nothing rather than turn the logger off by adjusting its level.

Answer (score 1):

The Struts 2 framework produces warnings if no action is found in the runtime configuration while rendering the JSP page when the application is configured to run in the `struts.devMode`. It helps the developer to resolve inappropriate mapping of the actions in the Struts tags. However, the action mapping not always inferred statically but at runtime. So, the tags should be able to find mappings from the attributes in the value stack. But the struts tags is only executed in the action context that won't be available when you redirect from the error page. Make sure you have correct URL that is mapped to the Struts action when redirected to it.